# Blog on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, blogs, jekyll, hyde

Hi i'm trying to host my blog on Google App Engine (Google quality & free ...) i looked everywhere for a solution.

I love [jekyll project](http://jekyllrb.com/) but since it's developed with ruby i can't host it on appengine.

I found [hyde project](http://hyde.github.com/) ( which kind of python implemented version of [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)) i'm thinking to use it on appengine, Are there anyone who's already using it on google appengine ?

Comment: If you implement one yourself and have questions about programming while implementing it, we'll be happy to answer. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: well i was trying to avoid implementing one myself (it will need maintaining). I was looking for someone who already done it.

Comment: Have you read what is written in the page I linked to? Your question is off-topic.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it more on-topic. It's still not a question about programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blog engine for Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086465/blog-engine-for-google-app-engine)

Comment: You may find this helpful or interesting: http://blog.tonyscelfo.com/2013/06/12/use-jekyll-with-pagespeed-and-appengine.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most possible solution is "[microlog](http://code.google.com/p/micolog/)", it's a Wordpress like python implementation on GAE. jekyll is not very suitable for GAE applications, because it's workflow is Write-**Generate Static Files**-Publish. On GAE you *cannot* access the filesystem, so it's not very easy to have such a framework.

PS: if you like, you can generate static pages and store them in the database, but I cannot see the point of doing this than just store data in db and render them on the fly.

Comment: I loved customization of jekyll and hyde. Maybe i store them in database like you said :D

Comment: Besides the support of Markdown languages, jekyll looks like any other  web blog systems. Store the **static pages** in database is never a good idea and we usually render data to static pages on the fly and store them with [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache).

Comment: Bloggart (the blog system I wrote) stores generated files in the datastore. There are a number of benefits to it, including decreased latency (a single datastore get is far faster than the multiple queries and the template rendering required to render from scratch) and improved reliability (bugs in your backend can't cause your blog to fail to render).

Comment: @nick-johnson It indeed saves some CPU hours,but you have to re-render them manually every time you modify it. Any way, Bloggart may be the best blog that fit nepjua's need, you did great job.

Comment: In a regular system, you have to "re render them manually" every time a user views the page. I fail to see why that's better.

Comment: @NickJohnson The best place to store static pages is cache, and it's fine to store cache in the database. But I still prefer using memory(memcache) to complete this task.

Comment: @Mayli That's a false dichotomy. It's perfectly fine to generate a page once, store it in the datastore, and still cache it in memory for performance.